# Concat Related Function Returns Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to use Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated()](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function, but I am getting an error of:

> Error 3061: Too few parameters.  Expected 1

Below is the syntax I input into my query ->

```
ConcatRelated("Product","[_ProdInfo]","OrderNumber = " & [OrderNumber])
```

What should I change so that this does not produce the error and displays the results I am after?

Further explanation:

- Field Name is *Product*
- Table Name Is *_ProdInfo*
- The field to match on is *OrderNumber* and it is a short text type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ConcatRelated() link describe:

> If the foreign key field is Text (not Number), include quote marks as
>   delimiters, e.g.:
>       "[ForeignKeyFieldName] = """ & [PrimaryKeyFieldName]   & """"

And since your *OrderNumber* is a text field, add the needed quotes:

```
ConcatRelated("Product", "[_ProdInfo]", "OrderNumber = """ & [OrderNumber] & """)
```

Or with single quotes:

```
ConcatRelated("Product", "[_ProdInfo]", "OrderNumber = '" & [OrderNumber] & "'")
```